Why can't i borrow a reference to a lifetime object in a closure?
I am new to rust and I am trying to write a struct which stores a tabular data in a Vec<(String,u32)> format. But I also need it to be exposed in a columnar format i.e. I need two separate data members name: Vec<&mut String> and rating: Vec<&mut u32>. When trying the following though I am facing an issue with rust complaining about a lifetime issue.
pub struct ElementWithRating<RatingType: Display + Num + Clone> {
    pub name: String,
    pub rating: RatingType,
}

pub struct RankedList<'a, RatingType: Display + Num + Clone> {
    pub list: vec::Vec<ElementWithRating<RatingType>>,
    pub metadata: HashMap<String, String>,
    names: vec::Vec<&'a mut String>,
    ratings: Vec<&'a mut RatingType>,
}

impl<'a, RatingType: Display + Num + Clone> RankedList<'a, RatingType> {
    pub fn new() -> RankedList<'a, RatingType> {
        return RankedList {
            list: vec::Vec::new(),
            metadata: HashMap::new(),
            names: Vec::new(),
            ratings: Vec::new(),
        };
    }

    pub fn add_element(&'a mut self, name: String, rating: RatingType) {
        let mut new_item = ElementWithRating {
            name: name,
            rating: rating,
        };
        self.list.push(new_item);
        let x = self.list.last_mut().unwrap();
        self.names.push(&mut x.name);
        self.ratings.push(&mut x.rating);
    }
}

impl From<FileInput> for RankedList<'_, u32> {
    fn from(value: FileInput) -> Self {
        let mut out = RankedList::<u32>::new();
        let x = |(name,rating)| { out.add_element(name, rating) };
        value.into_iter().for_each( x );
        return out;
    }
}

It can be assumed that FileInput::into_iter() is returning an IntoIter<(String,u32)> and it seemed to be working before that. So I dont  think the issue is there.
My IDE complains about this line in particular
let x = |(name,rating)| { out.add_element(name, rating) };

saying

closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows out, which is owned by the current function
may outlive borrowed value out

But when i tried a smaller example without the lifetime mess, the compiler doesn't complain as can be seen here.
Why is the lifetime of out in the add_element function obstructing me from creating a closure which doesn't even last the function's lifetime ?

Your RankedList is attempting to be a self-referential struct which cannot be properly expressed with Rust's lifetimes. The conflict is just spilling out to the closure where it starts to matter. And in this case, the compiler is correctly rejecting your code since elements in a Vec are not stable and thus references in names and ratings would dangle.

TLDR: If you don't need to mutate the strings, use Rc<str> instead of String and &String (or Arc<str> in multi-thread code). Cloning an Rc is cheap since it only increments the reference counter without cloning the data. If you do need to mutate, use Rc<RefCell<String>> or Arc<Mutex<String>>.

@kmdreko I was expecting some error in the add_element function when i created and indeed got some errors when i tried to take its reference. But it got silenced, when i assigned the 'a lifetime to self. Eventhough i assigned the lifetime, I honestly didnt understand what it meant and why it solved that error in that position. Also, I dont understand how it becomes relevant only in the closure.

@Jmb I do need mutable strings. I thought of using reference counted pointers, but that would mean i cannot store the String as it is, and that has to be changed to a Rc too. Since I am learning too, I was just trying to see if rust's lifetime can be pushed to accept such convoluted lifetimes.

I've added another question to the dupes, &'a mut Foo<'a> (or &'a mut self where Self = Foo<'a>) is always wrong.
